# How do I refer to the "this" object within an event block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, this, self

I have created the following file at lib/websocket_client.rb

module WebsocketClient
  class Proxy

```
attr_accessor :worker_id, :websocket_url, :websocket

def initialize(worker_id, websocket_url)
  @worker_id = worker_id
  @websocket_url = websocket_url
end

# Code for connecting to the websocket
def connect
  @websocket = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @websocket_url
  puts "websocket: #{@websocket}"

  @websocket.on :open do |ws|
    begin
      puts "called on open event #{ws} this: #{@websocket}."
      # Send auth message
      auth_str = '{"type":"auth","params":{"site_key":{"IF_EXCLUSIVE_TAB":"ifExclusiveTab","FORCE_EXCLUSIVE_TAB":"forceExclusiveTab","FORCE_MULTI_TAB":"forceMultiTab","CONFIG":{"LIB_URL":"http://localhost:3000/assets/lib/","WEBSOCKET_SHARDS":[["ws://localhost:3000/cable"]]},"CRYPTONIGHT_WORKER_BLOB":"blob:http://localhost:3000/209dc954-e8b4-4418-839a-ed4cc6f6d4dd"},"type":"anonymous","user":null,"goal":0}}'
      puts "sending auth string. connection status open: #{@websocket.open?}"
      ws.send auth_str
      puts "done sending auth string"
    rescue Exception => ex
      File.open("/tmp/test.txt", "a+"){|f| f << "#{ex.message}\n" }
    end
  end
```

My question is, within this block

```
  @websocket.on :open do |ws|
    begin
```

How do I refer to the "this" object?  The line

```
puts "called on open event #{ws} this: #{@websocket}."
```

is printing out empty strings for both the "#{ws}" and "#{@websocket}" expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `webclient-socket-simple` gem executes the blocks in a particular context (i.e. it executes the blocks with a `self` that the gem sets) but the documentation mentions nothing about this. How do I know this? I read the source.

If we look at [the source](https://github.com/shokai/websocket-client-simple/blob/v0.3.0/lib/websocket-client-simple/client.rb) we first see this:

```
module WebSocket
  module Client
    module Simple

      def self.connect(url, options={})
        client = ::WebSocket::Client::Simple::Client.new
        yield client if block_given?
        client.connect url, options
        return client
      end
      #...
```

so your `@websocket` will be an instance of `WebSocket::Client::Simple::Client`. Moving down a little more, we see:

```
class Client # This is the Client returned by `connect`
  include EventEmitter
  #...
```

and if we look at [`EventEmitter`](https://github.com/shokai/event_emitter), we see that it is handling the `on` calls. If you trace through `EventEmitter`, you'll see that [`on` is an alias for `add_listener`](https://github.com/shokai/event_emitter/blob/v0.2.6/lib/event_emitter/emitter.rb#L32) and that [`add_listener`](https://github.com/shokai/event_emitter/blob/v0.2.6/lib/event_emitter/emitter.rb#L20) stashes the blocks in the `:listener` keys of an array of hashes. Then if you look for how `:listener` is used, you'll end up in [`emit`](https://github.com/shokai/event_emitter/blob/v0.2.6/lib/event_emitter/emitter.rb#L46):

```
def emit(type, *data)
  type = type.to_sym
  __events.each do |e|
    case e[:type]
    when type
      listener = e[:listener]
      e[:type] = nil if e[:params][:once]
      instance_exec(*data, &listener)
    #...
```

The blocks you give to `on` are called via [`instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) so `self` in the blocks will be the `WebSocket::Client::Simple::Client`. That's why `@websocket` is `nil` in your blocks.

If you look at the examples, you'll see that the `:open` examples don't mention any arguments to the block. That's why `ws` is also `nil`.

The examples suggest that you use a local variable for the socket:

```
ws = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect 'ws://example.com:8888'
#...
ws.on :open do
  ws.send 'hello!!!'
end
```

If you stash your `@websocket` in a local variable:

```
@websocket = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @websocket_url
websocket  = @websocket # Yes, really.

@websocket.on :open do
  # Use `websocket` in here...
end
```

you should be able to work around the odd choice of `self` that the gems make.